# Initialising template variables using initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11

I looked at a piece of code and I am trying to understand how it works and so here is a minimal working example

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A() : _mem(T()) {};
private:
    T   _mem;
};
```

The first thing I was not exactly clear about is the initialisation of _mem in the initialiser list. What is this technique(?) called? If I look in the debugger _mem is set to 0. If there is a c++11 way to do the same thing could I receive some comments on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this has a name, I don't know it.

What's happening:

`T()` constructs a temporary `T` and [Zero Initializes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) it.

`_mem(T())` makes `_mem` a copy of the temporary `T`. Note: A modern compiler will almost certainly [elide the copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) and simply zero initialize `_mem`. This still requires that `T` be copy-or-moveable, so `_mem(T())` and `_mem()` are not exactly the same.

The only relevant C++ 11 difference I can think of is you can use curly braces, `_mem{T{}}`, for [List Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). Not useful here, but very useful in other circumstances.

Comment: After I posed the question I "realised" that you can say int a = int(); and it is intuitive to think that int() is a call to some sort of default constructor which would set a to zero. I just wanted some C++ jargon to be honest :). 

Thanks for the C++11 supplement as well !

Comment: Sorry about missing that bit. I focused in too closely the syntax you asked about and didn't mention the really easy improvement in C++ 11, inline initialization.

Answer (score 2):

This is just to safeguard against an uninitialized `A::_mem` when `T` is a POD type or a built-in type (like an `int`). Using a constructor initializer list of `: _mem(T())` will default construct a `T` and initialize `_mem` with it. For example:

```
struct POD {
    int num;
};

// ...

A<POD> a;
```

Here, `a._mem` would be unitialized (in this case, this means `a._mem.num` is unitialized.) The `: _mem(T())` prevents that from happening and will initialize `a._mem.num` to 0.

However, since C++11 you can just use inline initialization instead:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    A() {};
private:
    T _mem{};
};
```

`T _mem{};` will default-construct `_mem`, which in turn means `POD::num` will be default-constructed, which for an `int` means it will be zero-initialized.